# Указатель на char

Tags: c++

Если я создам указатель `const char *a;` и буду передавать в него строковый литерал, то есть ли предел в размере этого литерала и как в таком случае будет выделяться память?

Пример: `a = "слово";  a = "большое слово"; a = "Война и мир";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const char *a;
```

Это только указатель, причем еще никуда не указывающий. Чтобы он куда то указывал нужно ему, что то присвоить. Чтобы присвоить нужно для этого выделить память и затем можно писать a=<что-то-что-уже-выделено>;

Если написать a = "Война и мир"; то все будет ок, поскольку под строку "Война и мир" уже выделена статическая память, т.е. попросту говоря, строка уже в памяти и на нее можно без проблем ссылаться. Соотвественно, в этом случае нет никаких ограничений по длине такой строки, кроме объема памяти в компьютере.

Comment: спасибо, вопрос глупый, но никак не мог найти на него ответ )

Comment: @Егор Соколов вопрос не глупый, у всех начинающих такой вопрос возникает. Работа с указателями далеко не сразу в голове укладывается.

Comment: согласен, указатели наверное самый сложный раздел для начинающих на плюсах, очень многое уже с опытом ничерта не понимают

Answer (score 2):

**В указатель** Вы всегда передаете **адрес** а не содержимое памяти по этому адресу.

Размер адреса (количество байт, помещаемых в указатель) **4 байта** на 32-х разрядных и **8 байт** на 64-разрядных компьютерах.

Размер элемента данных  в байтах возвращает функция sizeof().

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите загнать по const `char *a` (слово), то вам надо обьявлять массив на это слово - оно должно выглядеть так: `const char *a[n];` \ где n - это количество символов которые надо ввести, например, `a[10]`.